# How to Set a Record Value equal to Another Record Value in the Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a column in a table with values already in that same column. The table has many records, but there are values they may share with one or two other records in an ID Column. So say there are two records with the same ID value in the ID column. Then I want to update another column called Details. The two Records with the same ID do not have the same Details value. One has an integer in that column, The other has a Null. My question is, how can I replace the Null with the integer for each set of records containing the same ID. Below I will list a sample.

| ID | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 55.60 |
| 1567 | 85.40 |
| 1234 | Null |
| 4569 | 58.09 |
| 1567 | Null |
| 8965 | 77.90 |

I would like a query that would populate those nulls based on ID.

| ID | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 55.60 |
| 1567 | 85.40 |
| 1234 | 55.60 |
| 4569 | 58.09 |
| 1567 | 85.40 |
| 8965 | 77.90 |

The table I am working with is much larger in reality and has many more columns. These are the two I think are relevant to what I am trying to do. I have tried self joining it seems to error out. There is another column that differentiates IDs that are the same by being populated with 'Open' or 'Closed' that I did not include in the sample if that helps at all. This is on SQL Server 2019. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering that there is only two same id and one has value in details:

```
update t1
set 
t1.Details = t2.Details
from 
tablename t1
join tablename t2
 on t1.details is null
 and t1.id = t2.id
 and t2.details is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE and window functions in SQL Server:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(details) over (partition by id) as max_details
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set details = max_details
    where details is null and max_details is not null;
```